# Should I use Expo for expo audio library or React-native-track-player?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-sound, react-native-track-player

I have my project which I initialised with 'react-native init' . I am thinking of using expo audio library because of it's robust functionalities . But , I have read Expo isn't the solution. It increases the app size. You've to eject it in the end. So can anyone suggest me which woulod be a better solution in this case?

Some of the shortcomings of Expo:

1. Does not play nicely with Hot reloading
2. Linking with third party library can be cumbersome sometimes.(Expo include the facebook sdk which is a overhead.)
3. Poor notification service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a project first made with expo , then after few time , got to realize the limitations. I would surely say expo is only for learning react native. You should never use expo for production. Here are the few things ive observed which i would like to share :

1. Expo app size is huge and app becomes very laggy .
2. You cant use libraries where linking is required and thats a big no no.
3. You dont have hold over app size bundling , specially in android as you can use a few tweaks like hermes etc to make your app more faster.
4. And you can always use expo libraries in react native by using https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules

I would suggest you should use bare react native  rather than expo.

Hope it helps . feel free for doubts

Comment: on the one hand, expo makes life so much easier for a basic react-native project, but on the other hand I see that because "linking" is not supported with expo, that's a big minus. I can't seem to be able to get the uesr's  volume (I need to know if volume is off/muted before playing an audio). Expo is great in many ways but is limited